# Web site responsiveness issue with images and right aligned text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've tried to make my website responsive but I am running into two major issues.
I have a right aligned text that disappears off the screen when I reduce the width of the window instead of remaining aligned. I've tried `margin-right: auto;` but it doesn't work. This right aligned text I want to make responsive is also on the same line as a `<li>` item

```
<li><h3><a href="..\Menu\Kid's_Menu.html">Kid's menu<span class="tabbed_text">25,50 lei</span></a></h3> </li>
<li><h3><a href="..\Menu\Menu_1.html">Menu #1<span class="tabbed_text">25,50 lei</span></a></h3> </li>
<li><h3><a href="..\Menu\Menu_2.html">Menu #2<span class="tabbed_text">25,50 lei</span></a></h3></li>
<li><h3><a href="..\Menu\Menu_3.html">Menu #3<span class="tabbed_text">25,50 lei</span></a></h3></li>
```

This is the html I used

```
.tabbed_text{
  display:inline-block;
  
  font-family: "caveat";
  font-size: 30px;
  position:absolute;
  left:1750px;
  
}
li{
  font-family: "cattie";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

this is the css use for them
[image]

This is how they look like on screen

The second issue is related to an image:

[image]

This it how it looks like on fullscreen but when I shrink the window it ends up like this:

[image]

this is the css I used for the image:

```
.small_logo{
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:3%;
  left:34%;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue 1:

You set `span` tag is `position:absolute;left:1750px;`
=> so you can not make it responsively when you shink.

**HTML:**

```
 <ol>
  <li>
   <div>
     <a href="..\Menu\Kid's_Menu.html">Kid's menu</a>
     <span class="tabbed_text">25,50 lei</span>
   </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  font-family: "caveat";
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
a {
  font-family: "caveat";
  font-size: 30px;
}
li {
  font-family: "cattie";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

You can see the sample [here](https://codepen.io/oang-phm/pen/rNyjopB):

#### Issue 2:

I will help when you clear your question!

Comment: About issue 2. The image I have on the top where I shared the screenshot moves with the page when I resize it so if the with is too little it ends up overlapping the text and I want it to stay near the text for any screen size. Also thanks for the help with the first problem, it works perfectly.

Comment: @RaresAmza you should remove `position:absolute; top:3%;left:34%;` and just add `margin-right: 30px` if you just need have a distance between them